# Date not showing with Concatenation formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

[image]

Having issues with the Concatonation formula - have tried formatting the date but it's not showing in the cell with the following formula:
`=IF(D5479<>"",CONCATENATE("RHU","-",E5479,"/",C5479,"-",A5479),"")`

Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Instead of a screen shot, can you put the formula in your OP? (Use the code tags), and same with the data?

Comment: =IF(D5479<>"",CONCATENATE("RHU","-",E5479,"/",C5479,"-",A5479),"") is the formula, it's worked on all of the other lines I've got on my spreadsheet but for 4 lines it's showing the date as a number. Thank you for responding.

Comment: We don't know what you are trying to achieve. What are you getting from E5479, C5479, and A5479? I assume Integers? What do you want your output to be? Also put @username before your responses for the person you are replying to when you put a comment so they know you posted something. This will help you keep getting responses and an answer

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores dates as serial numbers (the number of days since 1/1/1900). If you pass an Excel date into a concatenation formula, it will pass the unformatted serial number instead of the formatted cell contents that show on the sheet.

To get around this, use the `TEXT` function to format the date before it is passed to the `CONCATENATE` function.

```
=IF(D5479<>"",CONCATENATE("RHU","-",E5479,"/",TEXT(C5479,"dd/mm/yyyy"),"-",A5479),"")
```

You may change the date format, i.e., the `"dd/mm/yyyy"` argument in the `TEXT` function, to meet your needs. The one I've provided appears to match the date format you have on your sheet.